# Why does nothing happen when clicking Lavalamp menu (in jQuery & ASP.net)?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, lavalamp

I just made a lavalamp menu with jQuery. The problem is when I click on the menuitems nothing happens. But I have to navigate to another page. 
This is the HTML code:

```
    <ul class="lavaLampNoImage" id="1">
        <li class="current"><asp:HyperLink ID="hplMeldingen" runat="server" 
            NavigateUrl="~/Overzichtscherm.aspx">Overzicht</asp:HyperLink></li>
        <li><asp:HyperLink ID="hplRapporteringen" runat="server" 
            NavigateUrl="~/Rapporteringen.aspx">Rapporteringen</asp:HyperLink></li>
        <li><a href="/Overzichtscherm.aspx">Travel</a></li>
    </ul>
```

This is the jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
        $("#1, #2, #3").lavaLamp({
            fx: "backout",
            speed: 700,
            click: function(event, menuItem) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
```

Can someone help me please? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Show the generated HTML and any javascript errors.

Comment: there are no errors, the problem is when I click on a menu-item nothing happens

Comment: `return false` cancels the click action.

Comment: haha, that was the problem didn't see it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return false` cancels the click action